# Facebook like button won't load (has 0 width)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to set up a like button. I followed the official instructions, yet it will not load. Inspecting reveals that it seems to have zero width. I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue. As you can see, nothing shows up:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qme8mbn/

Code from jsfiddle:

```
<!-- fb like script -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<!-- fb like button -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mylinkhere.com" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in order to load the facebook SDK in JSFiddle you need to use https.
(f.i. `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5` or just `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5` if you are already in https context)

Second, not a clear solution, but a workaround would be to force a set width and height to the facebook elements manually, like this:

```
.fb-like, 
.fb-like > span,
.fb-like > span iframe {
width: 100px !important;
height: 20px  !important;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8rutttoq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize your Facebook SDK like this

```
    FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.4' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3
  });
```

Refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.5) once. It may help you

Comment: Yeah, I don't need an actual fb-app or page to make a like button for a website's url, do I?

Answer (score 0):

Test with :

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work but isn't that the same code just without a ?version query?

Comment: The more important change is switching the protocol to https. Otherwise the SDK won't get loaded and the following error will be displayed in the console: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."